# insert in sql table from flask register form

Tags: python, sql, flask

I have a register form in flask with the following route

```
@app.route("/adgangskontrol/Opret", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
# Output message if something goes wrong...
msg = " "
# Check if "Brugernavn", "Kodeord" and "email" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
if request.method == "POST" and "Brugernavn" in request.form and "Kodeord" in request.form:
    # Create variables for easy access
    Brugernavn = request.form["Brugernavn"]
    Kodeord = request.form["Kodeord"]
    # Check if bruger exists using MySQL
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM brugere WHERE Brugernavn = %s", (Brugernavn,))
    bruger = cursor.fetchone()
    # If bruger exists show error and validation checks
    if bruger:
        msg = "Bruger findes i forvejen"
    elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', Brugernavn):
        msg = "Brugernavn må kun undeholde bogstaver og tal"
    elif not Brugernavn or not Kodeord:
        msg = "Alle felter skal udfyldes!"
    else:
        # bruger doesnt exists and the form data is valid, now insert new bruger into brugers table
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO brugere VALUES (NULL, NULL, %s, %s, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL)", (Brugernavn, Kodeord))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        msg = "Du er nu registreret!"
elif request.method == "POST":
    # Form is empty... (no POST data)
    msg = "Alle felter skal udfyldes!"
# Show registration form with message (if any)
return render_template("register.html", msg=msg)
```

My sql table looks like this:

[image: brugere table]

Is there a way to only insert "Brugernavn" og "Kodeord", which is the data you fill when you sign up?

When I try to do it as it is, I get this error:

MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'rfid_uid' cannot be null")

Answer (score 0):

The table description shows that the `rfid_uid` column cannot have `NULL` as a value: that's what the "NO" in the "NULL" column means.

Therefore you must either provide a value when you insert, or change the column definition to accept `NULL` values.  You can change the column definition with an `ALTER TABLE` statement, like this*:

```sql
ALTER TABLE brugere MODIFY COLUMN rfid_uid VARCHAR(255);
```

You should be certain that having `NULL`s in this column is not going to affect your data integrity before doing this.

---

* I'm guessing that you are using MySQL, based on the screenshot of the table definition.